# BrowserRouter causes Invalid hook call (react.develeopment.js 209) in React and React.Dom 18.2.0

Tags: reactjs

I have tried to add a **BrowserRouter** in simple index.js file , it compiles successfully but in the browser I get the following error:
`Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component`

to note , when I remove the borwserRoter from the code , the codes works fine

could you please tell me what is the cause of this issue?

```
import './App.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
import * as React from "react";
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
//import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";



const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container); // createRoot(container!) if you use TypeScript
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
   < App/>
  </BrowserRouter>,
);
```

I checked the versions which are same , I reinstall npm , I also checked no invalid hooks in the code

Comment: what is `react-router-dom` version you have installed and why there is `space` here `<  App/>` , which should be `<App/>`.

Comment: "name": "test_dom18",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"

Comment: the space did not affect the compilation

Comment: You don't have `react-router-dom` installed?

Comment: Great, glad your issue got resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question resolved successfully**.

No more views required here.
You have not installed `react-router-dom`.